# Here Geocoder Api returns information that I do not have authorization

Tags: json, response, here-api, geocoder

I use Here Geocoder Api. Accessing the line below:

https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Rua+dezenove+de+fevereiro+45+botafogo&gen=8&apiKey=myApiCode,

When I access my old account, I have no problems, I receive the entire list, however, when using a new account, created a few days ago, I receive the information that it is prohibited, returning:

```
{
  "details": "invalid credentials for ",
  "additionalData": [],
  "type": "PermissionError",
  "subtype": "InvalidCredentials"
}
```

What do I need to do for it to work?

https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Rua+dezenove+de+fevereiro+45+botafogo&gen=8&apiKey=myApiCode,

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2023-10-27T12:45:45.778+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "District": 1,
              "Street": [
                1
              ],
              "HouseNumber": 1
            },
            "MatchType": "pointAddress",
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_D36pwaEH49v0rDK8QaWiIC_0UD",
              "LocationType": "address",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": -22.9509,
                "Longitude": -43.18727
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": -22.95093,
                  "Longitude": -43.18742
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": -22.9497758,
                  "Longitude": -43.1884908
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": -22.9520242,
                  "Longitude": -43.1860492
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "Rua Dezenove de Fevereiro, 45, Botafogo, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22280-030, Brasil",
                "Country": "BRA",
                "State": "RJ",
                "City": "Rio de Janeiro",
                "District": "Botafogo",
                "Street": "Rua Dezenove de Fevereiro",
                "HouseNumber": "45",
                "PostalCode": "22280-030",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Brasil",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Rio de Janeiro",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```